# Does Sharepoint offer live editing?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document, sharepoint-enterprise, web-services

I'm hoping someone can alleviate my confusion.

I'm trying to find out if any Sharepoint versions offer something like Google Docs' live-editing capability. What I mean is: Two people can edit a single Word/Excel from two different workstations at the same time.

I seem to recall that this was possible in 2010, perhaps with an add-on, but I can't find it any longer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SharePoint 2010 , you can install Office Web Applications ([marketing link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps) or [technical link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431685.aspx)), that gives you live editing that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word client app also has the ability to support multiple users editing the same document simultaneously